# UILabel issue in changing width in autolayout

Tags: swift, autolayout, uilabel

i'm trying to change a width of UILabel programmatically. I know i can do this by

```
UILabel.frame.size = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
```

but i don't want to set the x and y value so that it works fine for every phone model. Any suggestion to over come this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not required that you add constraints for UILabel' width and height since they have an intrinsic content size, which depends on attributes like text, font, fontsize...

This post, [How to set UILabel only width and height and constraints programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31428795/4746087), written for objective-c, should give you an idea on how to tackle the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The fact you are changing the frame it means that you are not using auto layout properly.
If you are using auto layout and you want to change a label width I expect you to set a width constraint on the label and change its `constant` property and then request for a layout update. 
If you really applied constraints, remember that they take over programmatically frames, thus your new frame is likely to be set again at its initial value after a layout updates.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```swift
let newWidth: CGFloat = 100.0 //However wide you want your label to be
myLabel.frame.size.width = newWidth
```